# Count all values from column values in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count, numbers

I have a MySQL database and in one column, I have numbers (price) and I need to count all numbers in this column with [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)... How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to count the number of columns use:

```
Select count(column_name) FROM table name.
```

If you want the sum of column values then use:

```
Select SUM(column_name) FROM table name.
```

Comment: @RohanKumar OP can write code, if he can't don't feed him with code.

Comment: No problem, I can write php code, I just need this "select" prompt, so it's OK :-)

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE with PHP Code

If you want to count you can do it like this:

```
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name"

    // Print out result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Total count". $row['COUNT(*)'];
}
```

If you want to get the sum of one column, you can do like this:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name"
// Print out result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Total sum". $row['SUM(column_name)'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe SUM is what you really want:

```
Select SUM(column_name) FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [mysqli_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) like,

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(price) as total FROM tablename")) {

        /* Get field information for column 'SurfaceArea' */
        $finfo = $result->fetch_field_direct(1);
        printf("Total price:     %s\n", $finfo->total);
        $result->close();
    }
    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for counting 1 row in your database:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT COUNT(price) FROM yourtable ";

?>
```

Then you can use `$query` in your code to show the results.

In mysql (phpmyadmin) you can just do:

```
SELECT COUNT(price) FROM yourtable
```